# Is there a way of building a hash map of my result in springjdbc

Tags: hashmap, resultset, spring-jdbc

I wanna create Hash-Map out of the ResultSet in spring jdbc. The putting into the HashMap follows specific rules for every record. Is there a way how to get this done in springjdbc?

Well, to describe it better:

```
Id | action | object 
-------------
1 | view | article1 
2 | view | article2 
3 | view | article1 
4 | order | article1 
5 | order | article1 
6 | order | article3
```

As Result there should exist:

```
name     | views | orders
----------------------
article1 |   2   |   2
article2 |   1   |   0
article3 |   0   |   1
```

I am thinking of an solution without doing two selects, just storing every record i get in an hashmap like map< articleId,statistics >. This is maybe a wrong and too complicated solution. Sorry for any facepalm, i'll cause with this.

regards && tia
  noircc

Comment: What is the format of the resultset, and what are the rules?

Comment: thx for ur answer, i have made some edits at the original post to clear things up

Answer (score 0):

The ResultSetExtractor will work in this circumstances. I have found a helpful code-example [here](http://learn2program.wordpress.com/2009/02/15/spring-jdbctemplate-to-retrive-list-and-map/%20%2aExample%2a).